# jPlayer widget created with static error as result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, orchardcms

I've created a widged with [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net). Unfortunately I've used the same "Title" for a jPlayer widget twice. Now I receive an error:

Server Error in '/wgk' Application.
Sequence contains more than one element
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element

Source Error:

Line 2:  <fieldset>
Line 3:      <div>@Html.LabelFor(o => o.MediaGalleryName, @T("Media gallery"))</div>
Line 4:      @if(!Model.HasAvailableGalleries) {
Line 5:          <div>@T("You need first to create an media gallery on Media Gallery menu")</div>
Line 6:      }


Source File: x:\Intepub\wgk\Modules\Orchard.jPlayer\Views\EditorTemplates\Parts\MediaGallery.cshtml    Line: 4

Stack Trace:

[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element]
   System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4206966
   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ImmediateResultsVisitor`1.HandleSingleOrDefaultCall(MethodCallExpression call) +51
   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ImmediateResultsVisitor`1.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression call) +411
   NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression exp) +371
```

In MediaGallery.cshtml (found in error description above) is written:

```
@model Orchard.jPlayer.Models.MediaGalleryPart
<fieldset>
    <div>@Html.LabelFor(o => o.MediaGalleryName, @T("Media gallery"))</div>
    @if(!Model.HasAvailableGalleries) {
        <div>@T("You need first to create an media gallery on Media Gallery menu")</div>
    }
    else {
        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.SelectedGallery, Model.AvailableGalleries)</div>

        <div>@Html.LabelFor(o => o.SelectedType, @T("Media gallery type"))</div>
        <div>@Html.DropDownListFor(o => o.SelectedType, Model.AvailableTypes)</div>
        <div>@Html.LabelFor(o => o.AutoPlay, @T("Auto play"))</div>
        <div>@Html.CheckBoxFor(o => o.AutoPlay)</div>
    }
</fieldset>
```

My problem is now, I cannot find or edit the widget with double used name. I would love to replace it to another name. But I do not know where to do this.

Please advice.

*** SOLUTION ***

I've deleted the last entry in database (SDF File). I've used this tool [Primeworks mobile](http://www.primeworks-mobile.com/Downloads/Files/DPCon/DPConsole_1.8.6348.57.html). Now it works for short time. After editing entries in jPlayer widget again it could occour same error again.
[image: jPlayer database orchard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching all tables named **Orchard_jPlayer_XXX**. One of those should have a duplicate value somewhere. Eg. column named **Title** exists in **Orchard_jPlayer_MediaGalleryMediaSettingsRecord** - it's a good starting point.

If you were setting the *Title* property of a widget - check **Orchard_Widgets_WidgetPartRecord** table also. If this is the case, my guess is you'll find the duplicate there.

HTH

Comment: Hi pszmyd and thanks for your advice. You are on the right way. But how do you open the "Orchard.sdf" database file?

Comment: It's an SQL Compact DB file. You can open it eg. in Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (via Server Explorer - Add new connection) or via WebMatrix - in Databases pane.

Answer (score 0):

There is something seriously wrong with this widget that should be communicated to its author (is it you?).
The title should not be used like an identifier.

Comment: I changed the title. I think it worked all great. But same name on widgets creates this error.

Comment: No it doesn't. That intrigued me so I tried, and got no error. There is something else, and I suspect it's in the widget's code. Try it with other widgets such as the HtmlWidget. If you find a repro that does not involve your custom widget, please file a bug.